# Stop UITableView from autoscrolling in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios8

I have a **tableview** that **auto scrolls** only in **iOS 8** when I open a new view using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];`

***Detailed Problem :***

Now I'm going to give a detail of how I'm getting the problem, it's particularly in iOS 8. Take any tableview having around 50 entries, scroll it down to make the 10th entry at the top of the tableview. Then select any item on the tableview. Use the below method to push a view controller on row selection in tableview.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // Open the New View
    NewViewController *newVC = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
}
```

Now you will find that on coming back from `NewViewController` to the previous ViewController, the tableview autoscrolls some distance. The tableview doesn't stay at the place of scroll it always changes its position automatically.

Comment: Tried your steps with a new project, but not getting the same problem. Are you doing anything in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear?

Comment: In viewWillAppear I'm setting the tableview background color

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Can you share more code?

Comment: If you cannot share code maybe you can try conforming to UIScrollViewDelegate and set a break point in scrollView:DidScroll to check the stack trace.

Comment: I have got the reason of the problem, it was because i was using a sliding side menu in my app. So that was the base view controller, now that i have removed it, it is working fine. I have seen that there are a lot elements in iOS 8 when you mix them together they won't work correctly.

Comment: @isoyaboy : thanks for the effort man :)

Comment: WWDC has a good video on how to implement a slide in menu similar to the splitview controller for iPad. Not sure if your using third party API, but the Apple solution doesn't cause the same problem.

Comment: @isoyaboy which talk is that?

Comment: @Arshu Can you help me. I have similar issues and  I am not using any slide menu in my app but still getting this issue.

Comment: @Vishu: You must be using a third party library or code somewhere in the base of the viewcontroller used for loading the tableview. It also occurs when we have a tableview with images or content with dynamic height & content size. Still haven't got proper fix for it.

Comment: Just remove self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = xxx;  It works for me .  The problem happens in iOS8 and does not appear in iOS10

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was using the new iOS 8 feature dynamic cell heigh. I was setting:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

The problem was that some cells were much higher than 50. Solution was to provide  delegate method `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` and return values that are closer to the actual cell height. For example:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        return 300.0;
    }

    return 50;
}
```

Another solution is to calculate cell heigh using `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and cache that value. Inside   `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` supply cached values but return default if the cell height wasn't cached yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = xxx;`  It works for me .  The problem happens in iOS8 and does not appear in iOS10